# failed to boot from usb-stick (ubuntu 10.04)

Tags: boot, ubuntu-10.04, usb-storage

I have an Asus 1201n and it has a dual core Intel CPU which has 64-bit compatibility according to Intel's webpage. When I tried to boot from my Sandisk Contour USB-stick with the image from this link: http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/, I got very strange message when I booted.

[image]

I didn't get an error message when I installed Ubuntu on my USB-stick so I don't know what the problem is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you create this in 10.10? See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/645818

EDIT: Oh and a potential workaround: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/syslinux/+bug/617779/comments/7

> From http://my.opera.com/toman/blog/setting-up-squeezebox-server-on-new-hardware:
>   After some fiddling around with the syslinux config files and still not getting it to boot properly, I found a deceptively simple workaround for this: Just type "help" on the BOOT prompt, and when you get the help menu, just hit enter. The system will now boot!
>
> Confirmed that this also works for me when booting a USB stick created by 10.10's USB creator.

Comment: awesome, thanks! the workaround did work! 64-bit is so much faster.